# Adding user input when adding product to cart

Tags: virtocommerce

I'm trying to add a textbox to accept user input before they add that product to the cart. I need to add the content of that textbox as an option to that particular lineItem but so far I haven't been able to, i.e., adding that text as an entry in LineItemOption.
I already looked into 'virto-commerce.js' and found out (at least i suppose) that this new dynamic field needs to be passed inside the 'options' parameter but I haven't been successful yet.

Anyone else been through this problem that can help? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tiago, which version of software are you using 1.13 or 2.0?

Comment: Hello, I kept thinking I forgot something and that's what it was. I'm using version 1.13.

Comment: So is it working now? I would recommend looking at 2.0 version as it has many more advanced features compared to 1.13 plus a web based admin.

Comment: No, I haven't been able to get it to work yet. Is it a native feature in version 2.0?